# Vue.js: how to update the layout without refreshing

Tags: vue.js

What I want to do is to make Dialog fullscreen when the screen size is small. 
My current code is like this.

```
<v-dialog 
    max-width="600px"
    :fullscreen="screen_width < 450 ? true : false">

...

screen_width: screen.width
```

However, this way doesn't update the layout when the screen is getting small unless the user refresh the screen.

```
<v-dialog class="dialog">

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px)
.dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried this way as well but this didn't work. How can I change the layout without having the user refresh the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `screen.width` I'd be more inclined to track the viewport width, `window.innerWidth`.

The example below tracks both the width and height and exposes them via a reactive object on the Vue prototype. That object is accessible as the `$viewport` property on the instance. The `resize` event on `window` is used to listen for changes to the viewport size and update the reactive values accordingly.

Adding it to the prototype is useful if you want to use the viewport size in several places throughout your application. If you just want to use it in one specific place then you could move most of the logic into your component instead. You wouldn't need to use `Vue.observable` in that case, instead you'd just have a suitable `data` property for the width. You'd also want to remove the `resize` listener when the component is destroyed.

```js
const updateSizes = (obj = {}) => {
  obj.width = window.innerWidth
  obj.height = window.innerHeight
  return obj
}

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$viewport', {
  value: Vue.observable(updateSizes())
})

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  updateSizes(Vue.prototype.$viewport)
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  data () {
    return {
      dialog: true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/mdi@2.2.43/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.11/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.0.11/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      width="500"
      :fullscreen="$viewport.width < 450"
    >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title
          class="headline grey lighten-2"
          primary-title
        >
          Title
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
          Body text
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did work as I wanted to do.. Also thanks for good explanation